# Porting old make file to Windows

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make, nmake

I'm attempting to convert this make file to a Windows make file. I haven't done anything like this before, and need some help. I've done research but don't really understand the plethora of errors that I'm running into. Is there an easy way to port this? Is it possible? Could this be made cross platform for cmake? This is all new to me.

```
#FLAGS = -lm -L/usr/pub/lib -lefence -o
#CC = cc -O2 -fullwarn -TENV:large_GOT
#CC = cc -g -Wall
CC = gcc -O2  # at least for SunOS
#CC = cc -g

#CC = cc -O2 -fullwarn

#CC = cc -O2
FLAGS = -lm  -o

SOURCE = stride.c splitstr.c rdpdb.c initchn.c geometry.c thr2one.c one2thr.c filename.c tolostr.c strutil.c place_h.c hbenergy.c memory.c helix.c sheet.c rdmap.c phipsi.c command.c molscr.c die.c hydrbond.c mergepat.c fillasn.c escape.c p_jrnl.c p_rem.c p_atom.c p_helix.c p_sheet.c p_turn.c p_ssbond.c p_expdta.c p_model.c p_compnd.c report.c nsc.c area.c ssbond.c chk_res.c chk_atom.c turn.c pdbasn.c dssp.c outseq.c chkchain.c elem.c measure.c asngener.c p_endmdl.c stred.c contact_order.c contact_map.c

OBJECT = ${SOURCE:.c=.o} 

BINDIR = .

.c.o: 
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@


stride : $(OBJECT)
    $(CC) $(OBJECT) $(FLAGS)  $(BINDIR)/stride${ARCH}

$(OBJECT) : stride.h protot.h

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECT)

show:
    echo $(SOURCE)
```

Comment: What is a "windows makefile"?  You mean, you want to write a makefile that work with the Windows `nmake` program instead of a standard POSIX make?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for my misuse of terminology

Comment: OK.  Converting to `nmake` will be some work because nmake is really pretty different than POSIX make.  On the other hand your makefile is pretty small.  You could use cmake but I don't think cmake has an nmake generator so you'd be generating build files for Visual Studio probably; I don't know if that's good enough.